# `pip install mysqlclient` cannot find `mariadb` as it's obsoleted by `MariaDB-client`

Tags: python, pip, centos, mariadb

In order to use Galera cluster arbitrator function, I installed `MariaDB-xxx` v10.5.8-1.el7.centos from YUM repo `@mariadb`. However, later on `pip install mysqlclient` failed complaining about missing `mariadb`.

Package `mariadb` was actually obsoleted by a installed package `MariaDB-client`, but it looks like `pip install` is unable to find it.

Any hints will be highly appreciated.

**Partial screenshots:**

```
(venv3.7) [root@host test]# pip install mysqlclient
...
  creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb
  gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -Dversion_info=(2,0,3,'final',0) -D__version__=2.0.3 -I/usr/include/mysql -I/usr/include/mysql/mysql -I/root/test/venv3.7/include -I/usr/local/include/python3.7m -c MySQLdb/_mysql.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -std=c99
  gcc -pthread -shared build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.o -L/usr/lib64/ -lmariadb -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.7/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
  /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmariadb
  collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
  error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
  Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
...
(venv3.7) [root@host test]# yum install mariadb
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, search-disabled-repos, subscription-manager
Package 1:mariadb-5.5.68-1.el7.x86_64 is obsoleted by MariaDB-client-10.5.8-1.el7.centos.x86_64 which is already installed
Nothing to do
(venv3.7) [root@host test]#
```

Answer (score 1):

I've resolved the issue by installing package `MariaDB-shared.x86_64`.